# Replace Child tag value of xml under single parent tag using sed command

Tags: xml, unix, sed

Is there any simple way to replace value of i tag from `1` to `2` under parent tag `a` only using sed command.
XML file:-

```
<a><i>1</i><j>xyz</j></a>
<b><i>1</i><j>abc</j></b>
```

I have executed `sed -i 's/<i>1<\/i>/<i>2<\/i>/g' filePath` which is resulting into change of i tag value from `1` to `2` in both the parent tags `a` and `b`

Comment: asked 27mins ago. until now I haven't seen the comment like `"don't parse xml with regex. or don't manipulate xml with sed/awk"`?

Comment: Can the `1` be other numbers? If so you need a generic solution.

Comment: Is `<a>...</a>` always guaranteed to be entirely on one line or could it be split across multiple lines like any normal XML?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/^<a>/ {sub("1","2")}1' file
<a><i>2</i><j>xyz</j></a>
<b><i>1</i><j>abc</j></b>
```

Using `sed`

```
sed '/^<a>/s/1/2/' file
<a><i>2</i><j>xyz</j></a>
<b><i>1</i><j>abc</j></b>
```

---

Here is an generic `awk/sed` that will change any number to `2`

```
awk '/<a>/ {sub(/>[^<]+</,">2<")}1' file
<a><i>2</i><j>xyz</j></a>
<b><i>1</i><j>abc</j></b>
```

```
sed '/^<a>/s/>[^<][^<]*</>2</' file
<a><i>2</i><j>xyz</j></a>
<b><i>1</i><j>abc</j></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic approach:

```
sed -i 's/<a><i>[0-9]\+<\/i>/<a><i>2<\/i>/g' filePath
```

specific approach:

```
sed -i 's/<a><i>1<\/i>/<a><i>2<\/i>/g' filePath
```

Comment: post is not clear about value to change (1 or any value). Seems that this is limited to value=1 based on post and sample but like you write your sed, more generic in title.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/<a>/ s#<i>1<#<i>2<#' YourFile
```

Assuming that :
 -  and *1* are on the same line
 - structure is the same (space char, no sub class in  or several  tag per

This is a very specific request, a more generic is maybe needed (like any digit content replaced by another, ...)

In this sample case

```
sed -i '/<a>/ s#1#2#' YourFile
```

is enough

Comment: The value of i=1 would be fixed. I have executed the following generic command :-sed -i 's/<a><i>1<\/i>/<a><i>2<\/i>/g' filePath. Not able to get a result

Comment: `g` is not needed in this case and try to use another separator than `/` because it is used in pattern. By 'not able' you mean no difference in result (so no 1 -> 2 ) ?